# Count number of records with duplicates

Tags: mysql, crystal-reports

My subreport goes through a list of ID's. Each ID has a location assigned to it. The report is grouped by the location (Group #1), then by ID (Group #2).

In the table, the ID's should look like:

```
14600
14602
14602
14602
14700
14703
14704
14704
```

My desired output would be **2** because there are 2 ID's with more than one entry. How can I easily calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 DECLARE @temp table(num integer);

 INSERT INTO @temp(num) VALUES (14600), (14602), (14602), (14602), (14700), (14703), (14704), (14704);

 SELECT COUNT(distinct num) repeats
 FROM
     (SELECT
        num, count(num) as counts
      FROM @temp
      GROUP BY num 
      HAVING COUNT(num) > 1) a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a combination of `COUNT` and `DISTINCT`, in conjunction with ensuring that there is more than one occurrence. You can accomplish this with something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM table_name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This returns the number of distinct IDs in the table. In your case, this is **2**.

Comment: wouldn't it return 5?

Comment: Yes, my bad - got myself a bit confused there! To get the count of **only** rows with more than one occurrence, you also need `HAVING count(*) > 1`. I've updated my answer to include this :)

Comment: Hm, nice idea, but i think it still needs a tweak to work. Try this: select count(*) from (SELECT id FROM table_name group by id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ALIAS

Comment: Note: i am thinking on SqlServer. Maybe in MySQL is different.